# Android: Homescreen shortcut to certain action within an app

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

In an android app I am making, I want to allow users to place shortcuts on their homescreen that will make my app perform certain actions. So far, I made it successfully create the shortcut (they are created through the launcher, not through the app directly). However, when I click on them, it says

> Application isn't installed on your phone

Which I assume means I have created the shortcut wrong. The code I am using to create the shortcut is:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(ShortcutActivity.this, com.example.myapp.MyActivity.class);
ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(ShortcutActivity.this, R.drawable.clean);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, shortcutName);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Realized I had to add the following to the activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```